# undefined symbol: rax in Visual Studio MASM

Tags: visual-studio, masm

i am using assembly to get the address to the process' PEB, but i cant compile it.

this is the x64 asm code, but it gives me the error "undefined symbol: rax" which makes no sense. doesnt even matter if i compile it in x86 or x64. i have a separate .asm file that has the same function but with x86 registers and such.

```
.386
.model flat, C

.code

get_peb_internal_x64 proc
    assume gs:nothing
    mov rax, gs:[60h]
    ret
get_peb_internal_x64 endp

end
```

-- now the x86 version that does compile always

```
.386
.model flat, C

.code

get_peb_internal_x86 proc
    assume fs:nothing
    mov eax, fs:[30h]
    ret
get_peb_internal_x86 endp

end
```

Comment: For 64-bit code remove `.386` and 
`.model flat, C`

Comment: well that does not solve my error, it just gives me 3 different must be in segment block errors. what should i use instead and why shouldnt i use those?

Comment: Are you sure you are assembling with ML64.EXE? Almost sounds like you are assembling with the 32-bit one. Or if you are using a Visual Studio C/C++ project are you sure you set it to a 64-bit bit (x86-64) one and not a 32-bit x86 one?

Comment: i checked the file that holds the x64 code and this was the command line: ml64.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"x64\Release\modules_internal_x64.obj" /Fl"" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /Ta

Comment: and for VS, i used the default c++ console project type and as i said doesnt matter if i switch to x86 or x64, the x64 version is the one that never compiles, while the other one always does

Comment: EDIT: changed absolutely nothing and just tried to c ompile again. all errors went away and its now saying :syntax error:gs

Comment: 64-bit MASM (ML64) doesn't support the `assume` directive. You'll want to remove that.

Comment: it now works, thanks a lot mike! if you want you can submit your answer and ill accept it

Comment: You can self answer your own question with the info I provided. Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my issue thanks to @MichaelPetch

The problem was caused by the fact that i had the .model and .386 directives that apparently as ive read myself just now, arent used in x64 masm, and also the assume gs:nothing.

I have adapted my code into a single file and it ended up this way:

```
ifdef rax
else
.386
.model flat, C
endif

.code

ifdef rax

get_peb_internal_x64 proc
mov rax, gs:[60h]
    ret
get_peb_internal_x64 endp

else

get_peb_internal_x86 proc
assume fs:nothing
    mov eax, fs:[30h]
    ret
get_peb_internal_x86 endp

endif

end
```